# Process injection - 32 bit process to 64 bit process

Tags: c++, assembly, code-injection

The idea is to make a cross-platform DLL injection program that can inject into both 32 bit and 64 bit processes. First off, I know the instinct to this question will be an instant "no, not possible," but I had the thought of writing 64-bit assembly or 32-bit assembly into the target process depending on its architecture. I have no clue if this would be possible, which is why I'm here.
Any ideas?

Comment: So far as I know you cannot inject into a 64 bit target from a 32 bit injector. You need a 64 bit injector.

Comment: [This article](http://www.corsix.org/content/dll-injection-and-wow64) concludes that it would be an enormous pain (if not impossible) to inject from x86 to x64, and uses a helper x64 process to do it.

Comment: I've already dealt with that (probably a detail I should have included); I have built both successfully, now I was hoping to be able to combine the both into one executable. But if that's not possible, I don't believe it would be hard to put together the concept you're talking about.

Comment: You cannot combine both into one executable. Is this really all you are asking? Whether or not you can inject into a 64 bit target from a 32 bit injector? The answer is no. However, you can inject into a 32 bit target from a 64 bit injector.